# Bad performance of custom Listview, Listview Items Name gets converted from Database

Tags: java, android

I got the Problem that the Listview ist loading to slow, so that my array adapter laags a bit. i dont know how to improve it, or implement a AsyncTask in it.

```
public class RezeptArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public final Context context;
public final String[] values;




public RezeptArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_rezepte, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    //this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}




@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



    // DatenBank Abfrage Angepasst auf den Array "context" View
    final DBHandler_Rezepte db_Rzpt = new DBHandler_Rezepte(context);

    //Einzelabfrage der Datenbank Ratings damit Sie weiter unten verarbeitet werden können
    ConDB_Rezepte Data1 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(1);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data2 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(2);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data3 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(3);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data4 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(4);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data5 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(5);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data6 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(6);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data7 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(7);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data8 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(8);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data9 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(9);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data10 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(10);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data11 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(11);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data12 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(12);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data13 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(13);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data14 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(14);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data15 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(15);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data16 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(16);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data17 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(17);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data18 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(18);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data19 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(19);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data20 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(20);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data21 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(21);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data22 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(22);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data23 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(23);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data24 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(24);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data25 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(25);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data26 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(26);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data27 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(27);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data28 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(28);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data29 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(29);
    ConDB_Rezepte Data30 = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(30);



    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rezepte, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    RatingBar ratingbar1 = (RatingBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);

    //stellt ein das man die Ratingbar nicht clicken kann, somit bleibt die Steuerung erhalten. Sonst ist die Liste nicht mehr clickbar
    ratingbar1.setIsIndicator(true);



    textView.setText(values[position]);
    //TYPEFACE///////////
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/OFLGoudyStMTT.ttf");
    textView.setTypeface(tf);



    // Change icon based on name
    String pos = values[position];

    int KuchenIcon = R.drawable.ic_kuchen;
    int MuffinIcon = R.drawable.ic_muffin;
    int PlaetzchenIcon = R.drawable.ic_plaetzchen;
    int ApfelkandiertIcon = R.drawable.ic_apfelkandiert;
    int OthersIcon = R.drawable.ic_others;



    //bei dem Equals Vergleich musste ich die GetRessource Methode nach dem Context senden, da die Array Class Context heißt.

    //System.out.println(s); //DEBUG Ausgabe


    if (pos.matches(Data1.getName()))  {
        imageView.setImageResource(KuchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data1.getrating());
        //context.getResources().getString(R.string.Rezept_01))
        //ratingbar1.setRating(Float.parseFloat(Data1.getrating()));

    } else if (pos.matches(Data2.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data2.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data3.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(ApfelkandiertIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data3.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data4.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(MuffinIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data4.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data5.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data5.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data6.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data6.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data7.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(OthersIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data7.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data8.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(KuchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data8.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data9.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data9.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data10.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data10.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data11.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data11.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data12.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data12.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data13.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data13.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data14.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data14.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data15.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data15.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data16.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(KuchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data16.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data17.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data17.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data18.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data18.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data19.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(ApfelkandiertIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data19.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data20.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data20.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data21.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(MuffinIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data21.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data22.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(KuchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data22.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data23.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(KuchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data23.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data24.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data24.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data25.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(KuchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data25.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data26.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(KuchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data26.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data27.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data27.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data28.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data28.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data29.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(PlaetzchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data29.getrating());

    } else if (pos.matches(Data30.getName())) {
        imageView.setImageResource(KuchenIcon);
        ratingbar1.setRating(Data30.getrating());


    }
    else {
        imageView.setImageResource(OthersIcon);
    }

    return rowView;
}








}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing quite a lot that is not necessary. I reduced the code and added some comments. In short:

1. Use the `position` to find which data should be fetched (it could also be a prefetched list which would reduce the fetch from database to 1 query)
2. You should use the ViewHolder pattern to recycle and reuse views -> quite some performance improvement
3. You need to do "static" stuff outside the `getView()` method because stuff like loading a Typeface is quite slow.

Hope the below code helps you!

```
public class RezeptArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public final Context context;
    public final String[] values;
    final DBHandler_Rezepte db_Rzpt;
    //TYPEFACE///////////
    Typeface tf;


    public RezeptArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_rezepte, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;

        // Do "static/reusable" stuff here
        // DatenBank Abfrage Angepasst auf den Array "context" View
        db_Rzpt = new DBHandler_Rezepte(context);
        //TYPEFACE///////////
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/OFLGoudyStMTT.ttf");
    }

    // will be called quite often! Make it fast as possible!
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //Einzelabfrage der Datenbank Ratings damit Sie weiter unten verarbeitet werden können
        ConDB_Rezepte data = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(position);

        // To not do too much at once this tip for later: Use the ViewHolder pattern
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rezepte, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        RatingBar ratingbar1 = (RatingBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);

        //stellt ein das man die Ratingbar nicht clicken kann, somit bleibt die Steuerung erhalten. Sonst ist die Liste nicht mehr clickbar
        ratingbar1.setIsIndicator(true);

        textView.setText(values[position]);

        textView.setTypeface(tf);


        // Change icon based on name
        String pos = values[position];

        // data should contain the information which icon should be shown!
        //int KuchenIcon = R.drawable.ic_kuchen;
        //int MuffinIcon = R.drawable.ic_muffin;
        //int PlaetzchenIcon = R.drawable.ic_plaetzchen;
        //int ApfelkandiertIcon = R.drawable.ic_apfelkandiert;
        //int OthersIcon = R.drawable.ic_others;

        // apply values/data to the view
        imageView.setImageResource(data.getIcon());
        ratingbar1.setRating(data.getrating());

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Update:

For the problem with the icon, the solution might be pretty easy: You can get the icon by name. All you need to do is storing the name of the icon in the database.

When you have done that, you can use the following method to load the drawables:

```
public int getDrawableResource(String drawableName){
    return getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
}
```

So all you need is to store the icon name in the database so that data.getIcon() returns the resource id you get by using the above method.

Comment: I haven't deleted any comments, just to make that clear. You said yourself that you are a Java beginner (I will be nice and just forget the "my IQ is that high" argument) so my advice stands: You are hitting the wall of your current skills. Take a breath and a step back and try the following: Check a CursorAdapter and check if that might be a solution for you. Also try to understand your own code in more details (and you will see that you don't need to get all 30 data sets from the database when you just populating once of it!). My final advice from a "Master" to a "Master"

Comment: thanks for your advice, and thanks for your Help. It works now, the only thing that dont work is the String Call from Database to change the Icon.

Comment: public int getDrawableResource(String drawableName){
    return getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", "android");
} i dont understand how this works. i changed it a bit to. public int getDrawableResource(String drawableName){
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", "ic_apfelkandiert");
} But it dosent work? Do i have to do it in the Connection Helper? where all my sets and gets are?

Comment: but where is the connection between imageView.setImageResource(data.getIcon()); and public int getDrawableResource(String drawableName){
    return getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", "android");
}

Comment: I GOT IT... and its fast. THanks Alot. I made a Mix of my If thing and your Code and everything works perfect.. Thanks. The Only Thing i not understand is your GetDrawableResource methode.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up. The last parameter shouldn't be "android" but the package name. Basically the method creates the same result a R.drawable.drawablename would return. In my mixed up version the "android.R.drawable.drawablename" was queried so the result was 0 and you didn't see anything. My bad! I updated the code in the answer already...

Answer (score 0):

A viewholder saves the view information to avoid having to recreate it.

```
static class ViewHolder { 
  member variables...
  TextView text;
}
```

You then create the viewholder when you check if convertView is null.

```
ViewHolder holder;

if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        // create the viewholder for the view
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    // Reuse the viewholder
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.text.setText("string");
```

Using this pattern will be quicker because the findviewbyid calls can be expensive. This way you only do it once.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rezepte, parent, false);
        // create the viewholder for the view
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        holder.ratingbar1 = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // Reuse the viewholder
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //Einzelabfrage der Datenbank Ratings damit Sie weiter unten verarbeitet werden können
    ConDB_Rezepte data = db_Rzpt.getConDB_Rezepte(position);

    //stellt ein das man die Ratingbar nicht clicken kann, somit bleibt die Steuerung erhalten. Sonst ist die Liste nicht mehr clickbar
    holder.ratingbar1.setIsIndicator(true);

    holder.textView.setText(values[position]);

    holder.textView.setTypeface(tf);


    // Change icon based on name
    String pos = values[position];

    // data should contain the information which icon should be shown!
    //int KuchenIcon = R.drawable.ic_kuchen;
    //int MuffinIcon = R.drawable.ic_muffin;
    //int PlaetzchenIcon = R.drawable.ic_plaetzchen;
    //int ApfelkandiertIcon = R.drawable.ic_apfelkandiert;
    //int OthersIcon = R.drawable.ic_others;

    // apply values/data to the view
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(data.getIcon());
    holder.ratingbar1.setRating(data.getrating());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder { 

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    RatingBar ratingbar1;
}
```

}

Comment: sorry i dont understand. is it possible that you can show me exact what i have to do with all my stuff in my case? how i switch the icons. and how i get the right stuff working