# How to fix memory leak in GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, memory-leaks

After each rotation of GridView memory usage is increasing...

Setting adapter on GridView:

```
        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        gridview.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(getApplicationContext(), width, height, density, gridview));
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Adapter getView part:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);          

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }


    btn_ = (LinearLayout) gridView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.menuItem_txt);
    imageView = (ImageButton) gridView.findViewById(R.id.menuItem_img);

    btn_.setBackgroundColor(back_color[position]);      

    textView.setText(menuValues[position]);
    textView.setTextColor(txt_color[position]);
    textView.setTypeface(font);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageButton.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setFocusable(false);
    imageView.setClickable(false);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setColorFilter(img_color[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(img[position]);


    return gridView;
}
```

After removing part between "else{}" and "return" statement there are no memory increasing, so i guess problem is somewhere in removed code...?

Comment: use a view holder pattern

Comment: also what is the need for `gridView = new View(context)` when you have this `gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null)`. remove it

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
 gridView = new View(context); // not required
```

Use a `ViewHolder` pattern

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

```
static class ViewHolder
{
TextView tv;
ImageView iv;
LinearLayout b;
}
```

Change `getView` to

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 ViewHolder holder;

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);     
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.iv = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menuItem_img);   
    holder.b = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menuItem_txt);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}


holder.b.setBackgroundColor(back_color[position]);      
holder.tv.setText(menuValues[position]);
holder.tv.setTextColor(txt_color[position]);
holder.tv.setTypeface(font);

holder.iv.setScaleType(ImageButton.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
holder.iv.setFocusable(false);
holder.iv.setClickable(false);
holder.iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
holder.iv.setColorFilter(img_color[position]);
holder.iv.setImageResource(img[position]);


return convertView;
}
```

Comment: @mgulan specify the problem with more details. I am pretty sure using view holder helps

Comment: @mgulan post your updated code full and specify the exception

Comment: @mgulan edited my code. but i don't see a problem unless you specify the exception and the updated code. use `convertView` a copy paste error. typo mistake and look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works. might help you understand how listview works

Comment: @mgulan how about scaling the image down. Download BitmapFun.zip. try the code http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html.

Comment: @mgulan by how much is it increasing. Any stats available?. Do you see any performance change now and before using view holder. What is the expected result?.

Comment: Bitmaps are scaled. It's increasing about 0.5 MB per rotation. No performance change, it's fast...

Comment: @mgulan i don't think there is much you can do. May be use lazy loading. try the example in the link i provided in my previous comment. See if there is any difference between your app performance and the code in the link. The only difference is they load images from server and they use caching. The loading of images in fast.

Comment: @mgulan also comment this `holder.tv.setTypeface(font);` and see if there is any performance change ie memory decreasing

Comment: @mgulan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599669/bad-performance-of-custom-listview-listview-items-name-gets-converted-from-data/20599826#20599826. see this. Very similar. Plus here i have suggested ViewHolder pattern also. Using ViewHolder pattern does help. But i don't think there is much you can do since you say image is already scaled down. Apart from that `Listview` recycles views.